# Load Workflow Instance with external ID

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a WorkflowApplication to execute workflows. It supports persisting a workflow on a Delay activity, and resuming it. To resume it, I use the Workflow Instance ID as so:

```
public void ResumeWorkflow(Guid instanceId) 
{
    var instance = WorkflowApplication.GetInstance(instanceId, this.instanceStore);

    var wfApplication = new WorkflowApplication(
        (Activity)businessProcess, 
        instance.DefinitionIdentity);

    wfApplication.Load(instance);
}
```

This works great, but I want to start resuming the workflow based on some other bit of data than the instanceId. For example, let's say my workflow was an SMS chat-bot, I might want to use the mobile phone number to resume the workflow.

Effectively, I want to use the mobile phone number like a correlation handle, but those seem to be used only when hosting WCF services within your workflow, which is not how we are using them.

Finally, I should add we are using the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore, if that makes things easier (maybe we can query the instance store to find out the instance id from a phone number or something?)

Any ideas how I might go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to review the use of InstancePromotedProperties. These should allow you to extend the persistence of the idled instance to include additional information. Ultimately your looking at Store Extensibility [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364726(v=vs.110).aspx) link gives you a worked example.